# Connecting Human poses with BB

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-processing, geometric-deep-learning

I am trying to estimate the crossing patterns of pedestrians based on their poses. I have a large dataset that contains videos named JAAD dataset. I want to make a prediction of the crossing based on the detected poses. I dont have the annotation for the poses but I have annotations for the Bounding Boxes. Can you please provide me with steps on how to achieve that. I am confused on using that on a large scale dataset.

Input is my image/frames data
I have the Bounding boxes labels around the pedestrians and those Bounding boxes are labelled mentioning whether the Pedestrian will cross the road or not.
I dont know how to connect the Bounding boxes of the pedestrians with keypoint poses extracted over a number of frames.

Comment: I have modified my answer to give a better insight on my problem

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have removed my comment (and will remove this one), since you have adressed it, and it is good to keep things tidy and focused. Other people who know about this sort of ML problem may ask for more clarification - but I cannot think of anything else to clarify.